# How to hide bottomNavigationBar when keyboard is used?

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I'm on flutter, but I'm having a problem with the bottomNavigationBar. I use a GNav bottom bar, but when I open my keyboard to do a search, despite the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` attribute, I can't open my keyboard without the bottom bar staying at the bottom.

Here is the code :

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CRUDWords>.value(value: crudWords),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0), // here the desired height
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: MyColors.primaryGradientColorTop,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
            child: _setAppBar(),
          ),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) => onPageChanged(index),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: pages,
        ),

        // floating action button
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showMyBottomSheet(context, const AddWordPage());
          },
          backgroundColor: MyColors.primaryColor,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),

        // bottom navigation bar
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: MyColors.primaryGradientColorBottom,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
            child: GNav(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              color: Colors.white,
              activeColor: Colors.white,
              tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              gap: 8,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              tabs: _setNavigationDestination,
              selectedIndex: currentPage, // mettre à jour l'index sélectionné
              onTabChange: (index) {
                _pageController.animateToPage(
                  index,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  curve: Curves.ease,
                );
                setState(() {
                  _activePage = currentPage;
                  currentPage = index; // update the current page index
                  _bottomNavigationBarTapped = true;

                  // for animation in page 3
                  if (index != 2) {
                    globals.previousPage = index;
                  }
                });
                _setAppBarContent();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to keep at the bottom the bottom bar whenever I open the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it this way:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool _isKeyboardVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add the WidgetsBindingObserver to the current state
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Remove the WidgetsBindingObserver when the state is disposed
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    // Check the keyboard visibility when the metrics change
    final bottomInset = View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    setState(() {
      _isKeyboardVisible = bottomInset > 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Screen'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // Dismiss the keyboard when tapping outside the text fields
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Text Field 1'),
              ),
              // Add your other widgets here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _isKeyboardVisible
          ? null // Hide the BottomNavigationBar when the keyboard is visible
          : Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
      // Add your BottomNavigationBar items here
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's work fine.

But i don't understand why not working like this `View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0 ? Widget() : null`